# Error while opening jenkins.war

Tags: jenkins

I have installed Jenkins through installer. I'm getting below error when I'm executing jenkins.war file. I have closed XAMPP which was using 8080 port. Still showing this error. Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin>java -jar jenkins.war
Running from: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin\jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Dec 10, 2015 12:22:43 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Dec 10, 2015 12:22:44 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-winstone-2.8
Dec 10, 2015 12:22:45 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Jenkins home directory: C:\Users\dgulhane\.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins

←[33mDec 10, 2015 12:22:45 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.net.BindException: Add
ress already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:414)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:406)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:
214)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChanne
lConnector.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.
java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectCha
nnelConnector.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:64)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at Main._main(Main.java:293)
        at Main.main(Main.java:98)

←[0m←[33mDec 10, 2015 12:22:45 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@757942a1: java.net.BindException
: Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:414)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:406)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:
214)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChanne
lConnector.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.
java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectCha
nnelConnector.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:64)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at Main._main(Main.java:293)
        at Main.main(Main.java:98)

←[0mDec 10, 2015 12:22:45 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: stopped w.{,file:/C:/Users/dgulhane/.jenkins/war/},C:\Users\dgulhane\.jenk
ins\war
Dec 10, 2015 12:22:45 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
←[31mDec 10, 2015 12:22:45 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at Main._main(Main.java:293)
        at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:414)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:406)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:
214)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChanne
lConnector.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.
java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectCha
nnelConnector.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:64)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        ... 7 more

←[0m←[31mDec 10, 2015 12:22:46 PM hudson.util.BootFailure publish
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:237)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:267)
        at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:916)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:815)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:225)

←[0m
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins won't start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632992/jenkins-wont-start) - you need to ensure that the XAMPP service is completely disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's already some application binding port `8080`.

As the log says:

```
WARNING: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.net.BindException: Add
ress already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

Try to check which application is using that port and shut it down, or alternatively, change Jenkins port on the Jenkins configuration.

Answer (score 6):

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081
```

Or any other port than default will solve the issue. Worked for me.