# "Unable to access jarfile jenkins.war" getting this error while run the cmd "java -jar jenkins.war" in OS- windows 7

Tags: maven, jenkins

"Unable to access jarfile jenkins.war" getting this error while run the cmd "java -jar jenkins.war" in OS- windows 7

How can I solve?
i did installation as per what showed in youtube

Comment: Note: `running java -jar jenkins.war` most definitively does *not* require to be run as administrator.

Answer (score 4):

Command `java -jar jenkins.war` in `Win7` command line require administrator permission.

Right click on the cmd icon and choose the `Run as administrator` option.

It worked for Windows 8 too.

Comment: hi @luka-chapukhin, please add some context

Comment: Hi Andy, @Surendra-T mentioned that he ran "java -jar jenkins.war"  commnad in Windows 7 cmd, this action require an administrators permission, so just do right click on the cmd icon and choose 'Run as administrator' option.

Comment: @luka-capukhin see VonC's answer as some sort of template. It should help you to get my idea. You can add your comment in your answer. :)

Comment: Thank you for good advices Andy. Moved from comment to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue after I updated the jenkins version.

The error message was found in `<jenkins_dir>/jenkins.error.log`

---

Resolved Step:

1. Download your jenkins.war at https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/
2. Put jenkins.war to your jenkins work directory
3. Go Jenkins Service and restart it
4. Enjoy it!

---

Ref: [Cannot start Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077903/cannot-start-jenkins/24203530)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are executing that command in the folder where `jenkins.war` is actually installed.

Also check if the file is readable, and not preempted by another process (you can check that with [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx))

Finally, double-check the size of jenkins.war, to see if the download was complete, and the file is not corrupted (incomplete or small size): see the [list of jenkins.war released](http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war/?C=M;O=D).

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Prompt as Administrator in Windows . Go to the directory where Jenkins is installed. and stop the Jenkins service first, using **jenkins.exe stop**

type the command to change the port using, **java -jar jenkins.war**

You will be able to access the .war file of Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was adding .jar to the file name, like

```
java -jar jenkins.war.jar
```

in case that you face an error that says, "Failed to listen on port 8080"
There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632992/jenkins-wont-start-failed-to-listen-on-port-8080) that worked for me, by pasting the following on cmd,

```
java -jar jenkins.war.jar --ajp13Port=-1 --httpPort=9090
```

Answer (score 0):

do not create a folder for jenkins.war file
store it right inside downloads direction
then go to your terminal go to downloads direction not to jenkins.war file direction
then type java -jar jenkins.war
it will work

Answer (score 0):

first you must be in the directory where the jenkins file is located and write the code by running cmd in that directory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).